# How to plot error in composite simpson's rule method

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the error in the composite simpson's rule 
 ... Here is my code

```
for r=1:100
n=600;
a=0;
b=5;
err=[];
x=zeros(1,n);
f=@(x)cos(x)+x.^2;
h=(b-a)/n;
xexact=integral(f,a,b);
p=0;
q=0;

for i=1:n
x(i)=a+(i-1)*h;
end

for i=1:n-1
    p=p+2*(f(x(i)))+4*(f(x(i)+h/2));
end

x=(h/6)*(f(a)+f(a+h/2)+p+f(b))
err(end+1)=x-xexact;
plot(r,x,'*')
end
```

When I run the code I get one point in the plot .. I want to have all the points ploted in the plot , How to do that ?

thanks

Comment: What are the dimensions of `r` and `x` right before the `plot`? I think the 4th line from the end redefines the `x` making it to be `1x1` double...

Answer (score -1):

The simplest fix is to put `hold on;` before your code here and `hold off;` after it. That way, each of your calls to `plot` will add a point to an existing plot, rather than creating a new one. (What is happening at the moment is that you are plotting a point with `r=1`, and then replacing that plot with one for `r=2`, etc. So what you end up with is a plot showing just what happens for `r=100`.)

You might do better, though, to build up an array containing your `x`s as your loop runs, and then do a single `plot(1:100, xs, '*');` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

There is a conceptual problem in your code: you want to plot the `x` variable which is not function of `r` and that will never change for each `r` value. So you will plot a row of `r` dots with a fixed `x` value.
Moreover I think that, if possible, is good to avoid for loops in Matlab because there are more powerful and optimized ways to do things that you do with them. For example I will write this code in this form:

```
function [x, err] = compSimp(n, a, b)
    err = [];
    x=zeros(1,n+1);
    f=@(x)cos(x)+x.^2;
    h=(b-a)/n;
    xexact=integral(f,a,b);
    % x_0 = a
    x(1)=a;
    % x_n = b
    x(n+1)=b;
    p=0;

    % x_j = a + j*h   with j = 1, 2, ... , n-2, n-1 (no need to set again x_0 and x_n)
    x(2:n)= a + (1:(n-1))*h;

    % summations
    for i=2:2:n
        p = p + 2*(f(x(i+1))) + 4*(f(x(i)));
    end

    x=(h/3)*(f(a) + p + f(b));
    err(end+1)=x-xexact;
end
```

As you can see i've changed some code logic, following wikipedia for theory. If you want, you can also change code so that you can pass a custom `f` function to the compSimp function.